# Line feature, Merge and Dissolve

Tags: intersection, length

I have a layer with several polygons and a layer with line above these polygons. Its like a map and a road network on it. 
I have to find out the length of line in each polygon. 
I used the intersect tool to spit the lines. However, I have three roads(from same layer) and when i intersect it. Instead of getting three different attribute, I get three lines but one single line attribute. 
Could someone tell me how to measure the length of each line.

Comment: What GIS are you using?

Comment: And where are you getting the intersect tool from?

Answer (score 2):

It sound like instead of the intersect you may be using the merge. The three items are then what is known as a multipart objects. You can use the explode on multiparts to get the singleparts.  However If you use the intersect command correctly it should give what you want.
Be sure to select the Line layer first. Then select the Polygon layer. (that could be the other way to get what your results are).

**ESRI Desktop Help:**

> If you are trying to intersect line features, they must share a common
>   edge. For example, two lines that cross one another (for example, as
>   an X) share a common point but not a common edge. Use the Split Tool 
>   on the 3D Editor toolbar to break this type of line intersection.
>
> The Intersect command works on selected features, allowing you to
>   choose which features are intersected in the output, although you
>   cannot specify the output's attributes. On the other hand, the
>   Intersect geoprocessing tool creates new features from the overlaps in
>   all input layers or feature classes, and it allows you to determine
>   which attributes from the input features are transferred to the output
>   feature class.
>
> Steps: Click the Edit Placement button  on the 3D Editor toolbar. 
>   Click the features from whose intersection you want to create a new
>   feature.  Click 3D Editor and click Intersect from the drop-down menu.
>   Choose the target in which the new feature will be created.  If you
>   have feature templates for the layers in your 3D view, click the
>   Template button and click the template in which to create the new
>   feature. You can also double-click the preview of the template to
>   choose a different template.  If you do not have feature templates,
>   click the layer in which to create the new feature.  Click OK. 
>   Related Topics Creating 3D feature data Duplicating existing features
>   vertically Combining features from different layers (Union) Merging
>   features in the same layer Copying parallel line features